# How to get the value of a data-filter textbox in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I am attempting to implement multiple data filters within the same application but also want to be able to get the value of the search box if the enter button is selected. I know I can get the value of an input search field using `$("input[data-type='search']").val()` but is there a way to append an id so that I can ensure that I am asking for the right value.

Below is one of my pages that is using the data-filter:

```
  <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="enterNewName">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <a class="leavePageBtn ui-btn-left" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="b">Cancel</a>
    <h1>
      Enter Name
    </h1><a class="EnterNameBtn ui-btn-right" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="e">Enter</a>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" id='nameList' data-filter-placeholder="Enter Name...">
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is textbox here in this markup

Comment: I want the value of the listview data-filter:  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" id='nameList' data-filter-placeholder="Enter Name...">

Comment: The text that is entered into the box

Comment: Are you talking about this    
<li><input type"text" value="" /></li>

Comment: No, what I want is the text that the user typed into the search box. $("input[data-type='search']").val() will get the text but within my application I have multiple search boxes. Is there a way to specify which box when getting the value?

Comment: I would guess `$("#listviewid input[data-type='search']").val()`

Comment: Comes back as undefined. The id is being set for the ul not the filter. How would I set an id for the filter?

Comment: I would also love to know the answer to this question. The input field is generated by jqm so there is no obvious way to assign it an id or otherwise reference it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best method I have found so far, quite clunky but seems to be working. I wish there was a way to specify an id.

```
$('#nameList').prev().find(".ui-input-search .ui-input-text").val();
```